# AJAX not loading without page refresh in Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I added an AJAX script to my Rails app so that my form would automatically add a car object to the car feed. Behind the scenes the car is posting to the feed like it should.  However, nothing happens on the webpage until I refresh and then the new car pops up. How can I make this happen without a page refresh?

The AJAX script
**create.js.rb**

```
$('#car_feed').replace("<%= escape_javascript(render 'shared/feed') %>");
$('#new_car').replace("<%= escape_javascript(render 'shared/car_form') %>");
$('#car_errors').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'shared/error_messages', object: @car) %>");
```

Here's the form:

**_car_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@car, html: {multipart: true, remote: true}) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <h3> Add Your Car</h3>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :year, placeholder: "Year i.e. '1993" %>
    <%= f.text_area :brand, placeholder: "Brand i.e. 'Ford'"%>
    <%= f.text_area :model, placeholder: "Model i.e. 'Mustang'" %>
    <%= f.text_area :vin, placeholder: "17 digit VIN number" %>
    <%= f.text_area :mileage, placeholder: "Current Car Mileage" %>
  </div>
  <p> Add a Photo </p>
  <span class="picture">
    <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
  </span>
  <%= f.submit "Add Car", class: "btn btn-add btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
 <button class="btn btn-hide btn-primary"> Hide Form </button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#car_picture').bind('change', function() {
    size_in_megabytes = this.files[0].size/1024/1024;
    if (size_in_megabytes > 5) {
      alert('Maximum file size is 5MB. Please choose a smaller file.');
    }
  });
</script>
```

and the feed that should be added to through AJAX:

**_feed.html.erb**

```
<div id="car_feed">
    <% if @feed_items.any? %>
      <ul class="cars">
        <%= render @feed_items %>
      </ul>
    <% else %>
      <h3> You haven't added any cars yet.</h3>
      <h3> Add one in the sidebar!</h3>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Everything looks good in the rails logs:

```
Started POST "/login" for 128.252.110.217 at 2015-02-27 01:16:38 +0000
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gFDS0iSBZl38m/LMPXulLCxvNgsjMQWMA3P/K+VEVzzTvQfTShKud3UaCRRlz6jL4JFtnwFiA6jukBfxZ7WpIw==", "session"=>{"email"=>"andrew@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT 1  [["email", "andrew@example.com"]]
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://rails-tutorial-ajhausdorf.c9.io/
Completed 302 Found in 129ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should use "chosen" or "jquery input" libraries "rayan bates" of railscasts.com posted about them